# Mail.app signature preferences too big for screen

Tags: mail.app, screen, preferences

Because I have so many .signature 'quotes' attached to Mail.app, when I switch to that tab in the Mail.app preferences, the window is too large for my screen.

[image]
<sup>Click for full size.</sup>

I cannot resize it with the top corners, and I can't reach the bottom corners to resize it.  Moom.app is installed on the Mac, but even that will not let me change the size.  I have tried to rotate the display by 90°, in the hope of being able to grab it that way.  I have also tried to modify the resolution of the display, but to no avail.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's not a resizable window, even when you can see it all. There's no corner drag facility at all & no green dot. I think you might have to remove some quotes, but I don't have anything like a number sufficient to test.

Comment: After further testing… even if I do fill it with dummy signatures & quotes the window never expands at all, it simply generates scrollbars. Perhaps it's Moom doing this, not Mail itself?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I deleted a lot of .signatures, but no luck.  I killed Moom, and that seems to have done the trick.  Curiously, I can't now replace my .signatures from Time Machine.  Ah, well.  Not to worry.  I never used most of them anyway.